# What does the next parameter in LinkedList really refers to?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

while studying one of the Leetcode problems (https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/) I've encountered the following solution on YT:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next

class Solution:
def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: Optional[ListNode], l2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    dummy = ListNode()
    cur = dummy

    while l1 or l2 or carry:
        v1 = l1.val if l1 else 0
        v2 = l2.val if l2 else 0

        # new digit
        val = v1 + v2 + carry
        val = val % 10
        carry = val // 10
        cur.next = ListNode(valu)

        # update ptrs
        cur = cur.next
        l1 = l1.next if l1 else None
        l2 = l2.next if l2 else None

    return dummy.next
```

And the only thing I dont quite understand is why the return value of "addTwoNumbers" is the whole linked list starting with the second element (after presetted zero) and not only the second element of the linked list, to which ".next", in this case, I presume, refers to.

Update:

I understand why the second node is used. What I dont really comprehend is the length of returned value.

Take this for instance:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next


node1 = ListNode("A")
node2 = ListNode("B")
node3 = ListNode("C")

node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3
```

If I print(node1.next.val), the only value I get is "B" and not the whole sequence of data (including "C").

But in case of "addTwoNumbers" it seems it returns the whole sequence of data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is generally a question about what linked lists are and how to understand them; it doesn't really have anything to do with the code. It's not clear to me why there is a question; someone who doesn't understand this *does not, realistically, have a reason to create a linked list in the first place* (especially not in modern languages like Python that have built-in container types).

Comment: If you are only doing this in order to solve the problem on a coding challenge site, the site is expecting you to understand these underlying concepts before attempting the problems. For theory questions like this, I suggest [cs.se], or a proper textbook.

Comment: I probably don't understand the question. Why would you think the return value should be a single node - i.e. a single digit - when the inputs can be numbers of any length. nb: There is no "pre-settled zero." The dummy node is just a way of avoiding special logic when adding the first node of the answer list.

Comment: It's just returning a node.  It just so happens that from any node you can enumerate the rest of the list, but you can also fetch the data from that node.  The rest is just a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

The input and returned lists contain one digit per node, starting with the least significant digit. The second node is used because the first node is a dummy node used to simplify the code.